# snmpd pass_persist function not working with snmpwalk

Tags: snmp, snmpwalk

I have a program handling pass_persist from snmpd. It works fine for get and getnext requests.

Get on 0.0 returns 0.0, and GetNext on 0.0 returns 0.1:

```
user@debianbase:~$ sudo snmpget -v 2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.3.0.0
iso.3.6.1.3.0.0 = STRING: "192.168.153.0"
user@debianbase:~$ sudo snmpgetnext -v 2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.3.0.0
iso.3.6.1.3.0.1 = Gauge32: 0
```

But if I try to walk the OIDs I'm handling, it acts strangely. I expect to see a series of getnext requests from the client, but that isn't what I see. The output of snmpwalk on 0.0 is just the result of a Get on 0.0:

```
user@debianbase:~$ sudo snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.3.0.0
iso.3.6.1.3.0.0 = STRING: "192.168.153.0"
```

If I perform a packet capture, it seems like my application is responding correctly, but the client performs a Get instead of a GetNext after the initial response

GetNext on 0.0:

```
10:38:37.238144 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29006, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 69)
    localhost.43142 > localhost.snmp: [bad udp cksum 0xfe44 -> 0x6c7c!]  { SNMPv2c { GetNextRequest(26) R=607525872  X:0.0 } }
```

Response from agent for 0.1:

```
10:38:37.238892 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29007, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 70)
    localhost.snmp > localhost.43142: [bad udp cksum 0xfe45 -> 0x673b!]  { SNMPv2c { GetResponse(27) R=607525872  X:0.1=0 } }
```

Now I expect to see a GetNext on 0.1, but instead the snmpwalk client does a Get for 0.0:

```
10:38:37.239027 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29008, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 69)
    localhost.43142 > localhost.snmp: [bad udp cksum 0xfe44 -> 0x6b7d!]  { SNMPv2c { GetRequest(26) R=607525873  X:0.0 } }
```

And my agent responds correctly with the 0.0 value:

```
10:38:37.240000 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29009, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 82)
    localhost.snmp > localhost.43142: [bad udp cksum 0xfe51 -> 0x07f4!]  { SNMPv2c { GetResponse(39) R=607525873  X:0.0="192.168.153.0" } }
```

If I perform a walk on any OID that isn't in 1.3.6.1.3, the walk behaves as expected and performs a series of GetNextRequests, but skips over my 1.3.6.1.3 oid tree that I am handling with my agent.

Comment: Have you tested with `-v 3` just to see if it make any difference just in case?